# How can Ioad a different view for each click, without copy and pasting code or having lots of if statements?

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc

At the moment I have a side panel, with a list of button/links. Each link loads the main content with something different.

Currently each link has a corresponding function associated with it e.g.

```
function linkName() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '@Url.Action("CorrespondingActionName")',
        success: function (result) {
            var content = document.getElementById("content");
            content.innerHTML = result;
        },
        error: function (result) {
            alert("Error Message");
        }
    });
}
```

I could replace this with a lot of if statements, checking the id of the button and load the relevant info.

But there must be a better way to do it.

Comment: Add a `data-url="@Url.Action(...)"` attribute to each button with the corresponding action/controller name so that you can have one script (which accesses the `data-url` value) `$('button').click(function() { var url = $(this).data('url'); ..... `

Comment: ajax.actionlink may be

Comment: As with @StephenMuecke 's comment - strive to reduce any server-side code in your js.  That way your js can be put in a separate .js file rather than in the .cshtml.  To do that in this case, put all data from the server against each item itself (in `data-url` attributes) and have the script read that.  This also makes it highly maintainable as you can add another link just by adding a new link with relevant `data-url` and no code changes. (depending on how you wire up the event)